# this.store is undefined

Tags: extjs

I am a beginner in Ext library, I am trying to extend a grid panel and referencing its store from one of my new class records:

```
Ext.define('App.ui.CategoryGridPanel', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
initComponent : function() {
    var storeToUse = this.store;

    if (storeToUse == null) {
        storeToUse = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(StoreIDs.CategoryStore);
    }

    this.categoryRowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToEdit : 2,
        store : storeToUse,
        listeners : {
            edit : function(editor, e) {
                this.store.sync();
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.apply(this, {
        store : storeToUse,
        height : 400,
        width : 300,
        plugins : [ this.categoryRowEditing ],
        columns : [ {
            header : 'Description',
            dataIndex : 'description',
            flex : 1,
            sortable : true,
            editor : 'textfield'
        } ],
        tbar : [ {
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'New',
            handler : this.insertNewCategory
        } ]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
},
/**
 * Add new Category to grid.
 */
insertNewCategory : function() {
    var category = Ext.create(ModelNames.Category, {
        description : ''
    });

    this.store.insert(0, category);
    this.categoryRowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
}
```

});

the method inserNewCategory always throw can not call insert of undefined 
after putting some alerts I found that this.store returns null.
I checked Ext sample codes, but I do not do anything different.

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check what you see as `this` in your insertNewCategory method. You will be surprised. My bet - it will be button you're pressing, because you didn't do anything about scope of this function.
2. Read Sencha guides and walk-through. From your code sample it's clear you are using it in a completely wrong way - you don't need to do all this manual work to assign and re-assign store - this is all handled by ExtJs automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for two things, for answering my question and for giving me the hint for where to look.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the creation of your category object is failing:

```
var category = Ext.create(ModelNames.Category, {
    description : ''
});
```

I would put a break after this line to ensure that your 'category' object has been correctly created.

With regards to using 'this', I suggest you look up the dangers of it's direct use. Numerous scenarios can cause it to be something other than you expect.. See [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-gotchas/) for more information regarding javascript gotchas.